# Booksleeve setting expiration on multiple key/values

Tags: redis, booksleeve

Unless I am missing something, I don't see a Multiple Set/Add overload that allows you to set multiple keys with an expiration.

```
var conn = new RedisConnection("server");

Dictionary<string,string> keyvals;

conn.Strings.Set(0,keyvals,expiration);
```

or even doing it with multiple operations

```
conn.Strings.Set(0,keyvals);
conn.Expire(keyvals.Keys,expiration);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No such redis operation exists - [expire](http://redis.io/commands/expire) is not varadic. However, since the api is pipelined, just *call the method multiple times*. If you want to ensure absolute best performance, you can suspend eager socket flushing while you do this:

```
conn.SuspendFlush();
try {
    foreach(...)
        conn.Keys.Expire(...);
} finally {
    conn.ResumeFlush();
}
```

Comment: Thanks ;) btw ... inconsistency I also noticed was that Set takes a long for expiry and Expire takes an int.

Comment: It would also be nice to have the Multi-Get operation return a Dictionary<string,string> so I can figure out which keys don't exist.

Comment: @ChadGrant  there is a multi-get `GetString` that takes a `string[]` of the keys and returns a `string[]` of the values - they are matched by index

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach:

```
var expireTime = ...
var batchOp = redisCache.CreateBatch();
foreach (...) {
    batchOp.StringSetAsync(key, value, expireTime);
}
batchOp.Execute();
```